# NameErrors within a class

Tags: python-3.x

When I try to run this code I get a name error. NameError: name 'information' is not defined. I have no idea why this code isn't working on several examples ive seen code like this runs without issue. I apologize if the solution is very simple I'm new to python.

```
class information:
    def __init__(self, name, age, phone, address='unknown'):
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age
        self.__address = address
        self.__phone = phone
        
    def get_Name(self):
        return self.__name
    
    def set_Name(self,name):
        self.__name = name
        
    def get_age(self):
        return self.__age
    
    def set_age(self):
        self.__age = age
    
    def get_address(self):
        return self.__address
    
    def set_address(self):
        self.__address = address
        
    def get_phone(self):
        return self.__phone
    
    def set_phone(self):
        self.__phone = phone

    def __str__(self):
        return'name: {} – age: {} – address: {}'.format(self.__name, self.__age, self.__phone)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    h1 = information('John', 27, '5193467891', 'Canada')
    print(h1)
```

Comment: When I run this code, I see no errors. Make sure to post the actual code you are using, otherwise we cannot reproduce your errors.

Comment: Upon inspecting the code, I can see that your setter methods are missing arguments to them, e.g. `age`, `address`, etc, which would explain any errors you get when trying to invoke those methods.

Comment: Also (maybe the indentation got messed up when you were posting), but the `set_phone` and `__str__` methods should be indented one more level.

Comment: As an aside, to be PEP-compliant, the class name should start with a capital (`Information`) and `get_Name` should be `get_name`.

Comment: In idiomatic python, you shouldn't be writing getters and setters anyway